# Pushing into array does not give required result

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
$output["data"] = array();
// after fetching data form db

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $output["data"][] = [
            $row['inventory_order_id'],
            $row['inventory_order_name'],
            $row['inventory_order_total'],
            $row['inventory_order_date'],                
    ]; 
    if(($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'user'){
        $output['data'][] = 'user';
    }
}// end while loop
```

and gives this result:

```
{"data":[[1,"1","Hina","10000.00","2021-01-11 15:01:54"],"user"]}
```

but i need result like following:

```
{"data":[[1,"1","Hina","10000.00","2021-01-11 15:01:54","user"]]}
```

`user` should be in same array

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a reuse the same key. In your current code new key for `user` is used.

```
$i = 0;

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $output["data"][$i] = [
        $row['inventory_order_id'],
        $row['inventory_order_name'],
        $row['inventory_order_total'],
        $row['inventory_order_date'],                
    ]; 

    if (($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'user')) {
        $output['data'][$i] = 'user';
    }

    $i++;
}
```